# Connect two contour lines with calculated line length

Tags: qgis, vector, line, contour, slope

Is it possible to make a plugin for QGIS like PEGGER for arcview 3.2?
Problem is, how to make path over contour lines with a gradient in percent?

Formula is: K= e*100/G*M ; K=10*100/0.08*10000=1.25m

K- distance between two contours
e- equidistance (vertical difference between the two contour lines)
G- Grade/Slope ( 0,08 = 8%)
M- map scale

When I set a grade by clicking with mouse line would be drawn. 
[image: Input grade/slope]

[image: parameters form]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make plugin or tool like pictures above or video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OblXzu2Dhb8