# How to create a line through contours?

Tags: qgis, contour, digitizing, shortest-path

I am using QGIS 2.18.14. I want to create line through contour lines with fixed segments, automatically. I already tried manually with  'Advanced Digitizing Tools'. It works fine but too slow. The goal is, if I enter the length of the segment  e.g. 100m, automatically connect contour lines from a given point to a point target, Or from the selected contour line to the other selected contour line. I think this is possible with some python script but I am beginner in python scripting. I would be pleased with the answer that this could be done, so I would somehow, step by step, solve it. Equidistance of contour lines is 10 m.
[image]
[image]

Comment: So you actually want a line that climbs up the hill with a constant slope. I do not know how to do that but i wonder if it could be solved better by using DEM raster instead of contour lines.

Comment: Not only up the hill, it would be good both uphill and downhill. I have already asked similar questions with the dem raster.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131702/connect-two-contour-lines-with-calculated-line-length; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193671/connect-two-points-with-fixed-longitudinal-slope-over-dem-qgis

Comment: Naturally both ways, I was thinking about something like building a road that you can drive with a tractor. There and back.

Comment: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#create-least-cost-path

Comment: Thanks @csk, cost path is based on terrain slopes, but I'm limited by the longitudinal slope of my path, between 1-12%. My path represents the road. For every % I know length of segment. The least cost path is the cheapest variant but often does not meet the criteria of the road.

Comment: What if you update the slope raster so that everything above 12% is set to some very high value which would make the use of those pixels very expensive?

Comment: Terrain slopes are cross section of roads not longitudinal. Do you have an example?

Comment: I believe you know your area better than me. I was thinking about slope raster that can be created for example with GDAL DEM tools http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html but perhaps such a raster is not usable for your task because the slope value of each raster cell is an absolute number which does not tell anything about the direction of slope.